# Uniswap Liquidity Calculation issue on Arbitrum Chain

Tags: uniswap

According to the "Liqudity Math in uniswap v3", the liqudity of a position should be:

```
L = amt0 * (sqrt(upper) * sqrt(cprice)) / (sqrt(upper) - sqrt(cprice))
or
L = amt1 / (sqrt(cprice) - sqrt(lower))
```

I tried to calculate the liquidity of the below position on Arbitrum:
[image]
The nft token ID of the position is 69171, so I can get the liqudity by calling the contract(0xC36442b4a4522E871399CD717aBDD847Ab11FE88) on https://arbiscan.io
[image]
You can see it shows the liqudity is **50242219347523**, and we can do more unit convertion:

[image]
Now I try to calcuate this number with the uniswap V3 math:
[image]
This is the output:
[image]
As we can see, the code output is very similar to the contract output, but if we look carefully, we will find the unit seems to be different. I know the unit of the contract ouput should be 'wei', but I don't know what the unit of the code results is. Can anybody help? Thanks.

Comment: I think the issue is that WBTC has 8 decimals and WETH has 18 decimals, no? Internally Uniswap works with fixed point numbers, the prices show by the UI is just an abstraction.

Comment: Good point, actually I tried to input the token0(weth) with 18 decimals(change the input 1.972 to 1972000000000000000 wei) and token1(wbtc) with 8 decimals, however the result still not match the arbscan output.

Comment: It's not just the amounts, but the price also that needs to be adjusted for the decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked that position and pool. Best to query the current price from the pool's contract, for quick look the UI can be found at https://info.uniswap.org/#/arbitrum/pools/0x2f5e87c9312fa29aed5c179e456625d79015299c

The current price is shown as 11.9011 ETH per BTC, and there are 0.3122 BTC and 1.466 ETH in the pool. This gives:

```
price = 11.9011 * (1e18 / 1e8)
x = 0.3122 * 1e8
y = 1.466 * 1e18
```

The tick range of the position No. 69171 is 253300 to 259900. Use these values to calculate `sp = sqrt(price)` and the square roots of the price range boundaries, and from them, the liquidity:

```
sp = price ** 0.5
sa = 1.0001 ** (253300 // 2)
sb = 1.0001 ** (259900 // 2)
Lx = x * sp * sb / (sb - sp)
Ly = y / (sp - sa)
L = min(Lx, Ly)
```

The result Lx is 49905251975363.266 and Ly is 51071435112054.96. The Etherscan info shows liquidity `L=50242219347523`, in between these two values, which have a few % difference. A few % is an acceptable error given the imprecise input values used in this calculation; the UI shows the price and amount values in a rounded format.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explaination, it helps a lot.